# My table doesn't update when i put a data on "distribuidora" field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

My problem is my table doesnt update for my field "Distribuidora" , but with the rest of fields updates perfectly. Here's my code , maybe im failing in DB but i tried all

My Mongodb code for distributor is:

```
        takingstats.find({ distributor: distributorAux }, { projection: { 
        _id: 0 } }).sort({ rank: -1 }).toArray((err, takingArray) => {
            if(takingArray.length>=1){
               return res.send(takingArray); 
            }if(takingArray.lenght==1){
               return res.send(takingArray[0]); 
            }else{
                return res.sendStatus(404);
            }
        });
```

My JS/Angular code:

```
      $scope.busqueda = function() {
      $http.get(API + "?" + $scope.valor + "=" + 
        $scope.valor2).then(function(response) {
            if(response.data.length>1){
               $scope.takingstats = response.data; 
               console.log("Data received: " + 
        JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2));
            }else{
                $scope.takingstats = [response.data];
                console.log("Data received: " + 
        JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2));
            }
      }).catch(function(response) {
          if (response.status == 404) {
              alert("Película no encontradas para dichos " + 
        $scope.valor);
          };

          $scope.estado = response.status;

      });;
  };
```

[image]

Returns the data but the table doesnt update that

Comment: Are you sure it's not updating, or is the value is the same each time?

Comment: When returns more than one element the table updates dinamically but otherwise doesn't update but returns the data I console. I mean for distribute field

Comment: Can you update the question with the code for the table and its data bindings so we can see how you're currently attempting to get the data in?  All we can see right now is the result of an HTTP request, but not how that data is binded to the table elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's is the solution which it's working for me , when i have an objet i tranform it into an array of one element. In case someone's need i write the solution here

```
  $scope.busqueda = function() {
          $http.get(API + "?" + $scope.valor + "=" + $scope.valor2).then(function(response) {
                if(response.data.length>1){
                   $scope.takingstats = response.data; 
                   console.log("Data received: " + JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2));
                }else{
                    //here is the new statement for transf object to array
                    $scope.takingstats = [response.data];
                    console.log("Data received: " + JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2));
                }
          }).catch(function(response) {
              if (response.status == 404) {
                  alert("Película no encontradas para dichos " + $scope.valor);
              };

              $scope.estado = response.status;

          });;
      };
```